# Google Play Services (Revision 17) project, translation warnings

Tags: android, ant, google-cloud-messaging

I've just updated a GCM project which has a dependency on the Google Play Services library project. I've updated G.P. Services library project to the newly released revision 17.
I've built the GCM project from the command line using Ant in release mode. I get a few (about 6) warnings of the form :

> *-package-resources:
>        [aapt] Creating full resource package...
>        [aapt] aapt: warning: string 'auth_client_needs_enabling_title' has no defa ult translation in
>   C:\dev\projects\EclipseKepler\AndroidWorkspace\GooglePlayServ
>   icesLibRev17ForAntBuild\res; found: af am ar be bg ca cs da de el
>   en_GB en_IN es  es_US et_EE fa fi fr fr_CA hi hr hu hy_AM in it iw ja
>   ka_GE km_KH ko lo_LA lt l v mn_MN ms_MY nb nl pl pt pt_BR pt_PT ro ru
>   sk sl sr sv sw th tl tr uk vi zh_CN zh_HK zh_TW zu*

Where the *..GooglePlayServicesLibRev17ForAntBuild* is the home of the GPS library project on which the main project depends

I'm wondering if these warnings are important, and if so, how to get rid of them?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically that means that certain string `auth_client_needs_enabling_title` is present in `values-XX` folders but not in strings found in default `values` folder. In case someone would use language that is not covered by translations, there's no string to fall back to. I'd not really bother in this case. Yet, if you really want to get rid of this warning, you may create strings in `values` with keys that matches library's (i.e. by copying one translation from its `values-XX` to `values`

Comment: So does this mean Google messed up then, as the whole library project is their code?

Comment: I do not know, having strings to fall back is IMHO better, but they supply quite huge number of translations so it may not be any real life issue

Comment: Ah, I see it now - new to rev17 each country has an 'auth_strings.xml' in its values-XX. There is no such file in values. This was not the case for rev 16. Thanks all is clear, shouldn't cause a problem. Google are sloppy though.

Comment: In Eclipse, you can prevent this being reported as an error via setting severity of `ExtraTranslation` Lint Id to `Warning` or lower.